# Can I create a DNS domain for local use?

Tags: networking, internet, dns, domain

Is there a way for me to assign a domain name to a computer's local IP address, not for use with people outside the network?

Preferably with no need to buy said domain.

A example would to use `domain.com` for the IP `192.168.1.11`, a local computer on the network, and when I type `domain.com` in my browser it will bring me to whatever is on `http://192.168.1.11:80/`

Comment: Some routers can do this, and some can't.  Can you tell us what manufacturer and model your is?

Comment: @kevin whats the point of editing my post? I did get a answer, i don't exactly see a reason for you to change the question i asked. I didn't ask specifically for DNS.

Comment: @fredghostkyle http://superuser.com/help/editing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution:

Open `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` with notepad. Write in the following line:

```
192.168.1.1 domain.com
```

This change will be visible on your computer only. If you have more than one, maybe you need to make this on every computer.

---

More complex ways, if you need multiple machines to access this:

1. Check deep the menu system of your local router. Most of them have local dns functionality. Look for "dns", "name server", "zone", "local zone" or such menu entries. There you can set it up.
2. You could run your own DNS server on your network. If you configure your networked computers to use your new DNS server you would be able to push the new "domain" or "host" with a single configuration change at the DNS server.
3. You could find a free dns provider on the net (google for: free dns zone), and with it you could set up a zone for your *local* network. It were a sub-optimal solution, because it made your local dns out of your local network, and thus it has many disadvantages, although it could work.

Comment: This will only work on each computer that has an edited hosts file.

Comment: @Dan-o Yes, you have absolutely right.

Comment: Is there any way for me to do something similar on a DNS or router so everyone on my network will have that? thanks for the speedy answer!

Comment: Bring up your own dns server, look up for _isc bind_, then set your router DHCP server so that it sends out your own DNS server ip for clients. It's not that hard. DDWRT inside your router (if it is supported) and you will get compact package

Answer (score 3):

At one point, I was testing things like this and came across [Simple DNS Plus](http://www.simpledns.com/). It's basically just a DNS server software than can run on any Windows box. It's pretty configurable and did the trick for me. It's not free and I'm in no way affiliated.

[image]

[image]